# Get logged user every time the component renders under React ContextAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ContextAPI in a small React project, I use `HttpOnly Cookie` to store the user's token when I hit the `/login` endpoint.

This is `UserContext.js` shown bellow, which encapsulates all the components (children) in `App.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(undefined);

  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/logged-in`);
    setLoggedUser(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ loggedUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { UserContext };
export default UserContextProvider;
```

What I understand is when I log in, I `setLoggedUser` to the state from the `/login` response, and now it is available for all the children components of the context.

Now I can navigate to all components wrapped by the context and print for example the email of the `loggedUser`, but what if the email changed while we're logged in? I'll still see the old email on my components because the data is outdated in the state. And what if token got invalidated on the server while we were logged in.. (The only case we'll get updated data is if I refresh the app because that will trigger useEffect in the context provider and refresh the state again)

Should I also pass the `checkLoggedIn` function through the context's `value` property to make it available for other components and then use it in UseEffect in every component? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: remove the [ ] in useEffect function so the checkLogginedIn() runs every time

Answer (score 2):

After the latest comment if you want to check for email on every re-render then you can remove [] from useEffect as stated above in the comments by @abu dujana.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(undefined);

  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/logged-in`);
    setLoggedUser(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoggedIn();
  });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ loggedUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { UserContext };
export default UserContextProvider;
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, and as I said it's not only a problem for the email, I meant if there was any update in the user's data in the server, or more importantly if the token is no longer valid in the server while we're logged in and depending on state data. I want to know the approach the solve this kind of issue, and if it's even an issue to consider.

Comment: If that is the case then you need to keep checking the server in some interval or you can have a web socket implementation in your server and client to pull up the data if they have been changed.

Comment: Other option is to check email on every re-render of the component. Which you can do by just removing the [] from the useEffect hook. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: I don't mean to get that far and refresh using an interval, I was wondering if I make a call each time a component renders is considered a "good design" or there is a better approach to it. I only need the data to be fresh when I navigate to a component.

Comment: Check updated code and comments. I think that is the only solution for you.